# Prove that $k$ is of the form $pn^2 \pm 2cn + a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to do this problem (Underwood and Dudley, Elementary Number Theory, pg. 181, #53):

> If $p$ is a prime and $ap + b = c^2$, then show that all values of $k$ making $kp + b$ a square are given by $k = pn^2 \pm 2cn + a$ where $n$ is any integer.

It's straightforward to show that any $k$ satisfying $k = pn^2 \pm 2cn + a$ makes $kp + b$ a square:

$$\begin{align*}
(pn^2 \pm 2cn + a)p + b &= (pn)^2 \pm 2cpn + ap + b \\
&= (pn)^2 \pm 2cpn + c^2 \\
&= (pn \pm c)^2
\end{align*}
$$

However I can't figure out how to approach the other direction. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARGH, I figured it out as soon as I proofread my question. I'll leave this here in case this is interesting for anybody else.

Let $kp + b = x^2$. Then $x^2 \equiv c^2 \mod p$, and since $p$ is prime, either $x \equiv c $ or $x \equiv -c \mod p$. So there exists an integer $n$ such that either $x = pn + c$ or $x = pn - c$. Write $x = pn \pm c$ to handle both cases at once. Then

$$ kp + b = (pn \pm c)^2$$

which means

$$ kp = p^2 n^2 \pm 2pnc + c^2 - b $$

and since $c^2 = ap + b$, we have

$$ kp = p^2 n^2 \pm 2pnc + ap $$

which implies

$$ k = p(n^2 \pm 2nc + a) $$

as desired.